# Is there any way in RStudio to know from which library a particular function in a script is used?

Tags: r, rstudio

I have got a R script. I want to know the library of a particular function used in the script. In python the library name is attached to the function but in R it is not.

I tried hovering the cursor on the function in R script nothing pops up.

Comment: Start a new R session, run the script line by line until the function. Then in the console write the function *without* the `()` at the end. That will give you the source code of that function and let you know where it comes from (i.e. which package; or base if it’s a base R function)

Comment: You can run `?mystery_function` and it should bring up what package it is from in the help pane.

Comment: @jpsmith good approach but just have to be careful if there’s multiple of the same function name from different packages

Comment: @stevec agreed, usually it will return the list of possible packages (ie if you run `?lag` it will bring up base and dplyr options) so you’re right you have to know the context. Thanks!

Comment: How I do it in RStudio: Place the cursor on the function and hit F1.

Answer (score 2):

"In python the library name is attached to the function but in R it is not."

If you print the function, you will see the package namespace containing it. For instance:

```
print(print)
#function (x, ...) 
#UseMethod("print")
#<bytecode: 0x0000018474a86850>
#<environment: namespace:base>
```

The `environment` function will give just the namespace:

```
environment(print)
#<environment: namespace:base>
```

However, be carefull with generic functions. Usually, you are interested in the method they dispatch to. For that you need to derive the class of the object and check the namespace containing the corresponding method. For instance:

```
class(print)
#[1] "function"

environment(print.function)
#<environment: namespace:base>
```

If the method is not exported from the namespace, `getAnywhere` can help:

```
getAnywhere(print.function)
#A single object matching ‘print.function’ was found
#It was found in the following places
#  package:base
#  registered S3 method for print from namespace base
#  namespace:base
#with value
#
#function (x, useSource = TRUE, ...) 
#print.default(x, useSource = useSource, ...)
#<bytecode: 0x0000018471f715a8>
#<environment: namespace:base>
```